# Segue to class using UIScrollView and NSNotificationCenter

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, segue, nsnotificationcenter

I'm making an iPhone app that presents a UIScrollView with data in rows obtained from a database.

ViewController1:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(eventHandler:) name:@"onEvent" object:nil];
}

- (IBAction) eventHandler:(NSNotification *) notification {
    [RequestRowView initialize];
}
```

In RequestRowView:

-(IBAction)onSelected:(id)sender {

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"onEvent" object:nil];

    Globals* global = [Globals getInstance];
    global.fulfillRequestLocationName = name;
    global.fulfillRequestCityStateZip = cityStateZip;
    global.fulfillRequestExpirationDate = endDateTime;

    NSLog(@"global vars are %@ %@ %@", global.fulfillRequestLocationName, global.fulfillRequestCityStateZip, global.fulfillRequestExpirationDate);   
}
```

The rows in the UIScrollView display fine, but whenever I click the row, it just does the NSLog.

My question is: How do I get it to segue to another view?

Among some things, I've created a hidden button in the class that does an IBAction function with [performSegueWithIdentifier], but I get the error that the receiving class doesn't have that identifier.

Is this an issue I don't understand with NSNotificationCenter or am I calling the instance of the class incorrectly when I create the button?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I created a custom button segue in the View Controller (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XApYtAlRDVE) and defined [self nextButton] in my eventHandler function.

However, when it segues to the next view, the variables don't display immediately. I click back to "Home" and then select the row again, and only then do the variables display in their respective labels.

Does this have something to do with how global variables are defined within Xcode?